# Prevent brute force attacks by redirects

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

When reviewing the log of my TYPO3 9.5 instance, I find regular attempts to get to a login mask. For example, there are calls after the pattern *https: //domain.tld/wp-login.php*, *https: //domain.tld/wp-admin*, *https: //domain.tld/administrator/index.php* etc, which end up in a TYPO3 Exception.
Instead, I would like to redirect such calls, e.g. to the homepage. What would be best practise to realise this?
I already tried to create a redirect using the Site Management module, unfortunately this ends up in a TYPO3 exception `The Fluid template files" "could not be loaded.` caused by the request for *https: //domain.tld/index.php*.

Comment: Why do you want to redirect them? I would assume you want to block these as soon as possible before they even start using resources (PHP, database, etc.). This is what I do, I  give these requests a 404 or 401 in the webserver configuration before they even reach the TYPO3 site.

Answer (score 5):

Given that the traffic you mention is non-desirable traffic, I would suggest to just show a 404 instead of serving the homepage.

So you can just add a "404 Page not found" error handler in the Site Configuration through the backend module. If an non existing url is requested, the error handler 
will display your 404 content.

If you have a lot of "bad traffic" that overloads your server, you can go further 
 with some deny rules in your htaccess, or even with fail2ban.

Comment: I totally agree with this approach. In fact, requests to `wp-login*` and `wp-admin*` are typical scans for WordPress sites, which you usually don't want to hit the TYPO3 instance. I'd simply reject them by adding a web server configuration as suggested by @dogawaf